# Scala generics not clear to me

Tags: scala, generics

```
class A {

    def x(): Unit = {
      println("tftf")
    }

}

def t[A](x: A): Unit = {
    x.x    // <- error at this line 
}
```

I get compile error - type mismatch;  found   : x.type (with underlying type A)  required: ?{def x: ?} Note that implicit conversions are not applicable because they are ambiguous:  both method any2Ensuring in object Predef of type [A](x: A)Ensuring[A]  and method any2ArrowAssoc in object Predef of type [A](x: A)ArrowAssoc[A]  are possible conversion functions from x.type to ?{def x: ?}
- t

Can someone explain this in English, please? I am new to Scala.

Comment: you can left A as a class name, and use function like `def t[T](x: A): Unit = ...` if that will make it clear (in addition to LimbSoup answer)

Answer (score 5):

`t`'s generic parameter named `A` shadows the class named `A`.

What you've written is equivalent to:

```
class A {
    def x(): Unit = {
      println("tftf")
    }
}

def t[B](x: B): Unit = {
    x.x    // <- error at this line 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `A` is a concrete type (a class). But in the function `t[A](x: A): Unit`, you're trying to use it as a type parameter. There's nothing generic about it.

A simple example of using generics with the function would be something like:

```
def t[A](x: A): Unit = println("Here is the parameter x: " + x)
```

This function will accept any type, and simply print it to the console.

Answer (score 2):

in your `def t[A](x: A)`, `A` is a generic type parameter and has nothing to do with the `class A` you defined. you can name it whatever you want, like `def t[T](x: T)`.

what you want to do actually is:

```
def t[B <: A](x: B): Unit = {
   x.x    //  won't error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two sources of confusion here:

1. Your type parameter A shadows class type A.
2. Type parameter A is unconstrained, which implicitly means `[A <: Any]`, and `Any` doesn't have the member `x`. The confusing error message comes from the compiler attempting to apply an implicit conversion from `Any` to something that has a member `x`.

You simply want a function that takes a parameter that is a subtype of A, but you don't need a type parameter for this since any subtype of class type A is a valid substitution for class type A as a function parameter.

Hence the solution is simply this:

```
def t(a: A) {
    a.x()
}
```